# How to draw text to the screen using glutBitmapCharacter()

Tags: c++, freeglut

I am attempting to draw a string of text to my game window using the glutBitmapCharacter() function, however the text only draws the first word. I assume this means the glutBitmapCharacter() function sees a space as a end point.

Could somebody help me draw a string of text which includes spaces?

This is my first question on Stack Overflow, I hope it's not too vague or been answered before.

```
//Below is the check I am using for spaces and attempting to draw this space

char space = ' ';
if(i == space)
  glutBitmapCharacter(GLUT_BITMAP_TIMES_ROMAN_24,space);
else
  glutBitmapCharacter(GLUT_BITMAP_TIMES_ROMAN_24,s[i]);




//The text I am trying to write to screen (global for testing)
string message = "hello world";




//The function for drawing text
void drawString(void* font, float x, float y, string s) 
{
    glRasterPos3f(x, y, 0.0);
    for (char i = 0; i < s.length(); ++i) 
        {
        char space = ' ';
        if(i == space)
            glutBitmapCharacter(GLUT_BITMAP_TIMES_ROMAN_24,space);
        else
                glutBitmapCharacter(GLUT_BITMAP_TIMES_ROMAN_24,s[i]);
    }
}


//the draw function
void draw()
{
    if (message.length() > 0)
        drawString(GLUT_BITMAP_HELVETICA_18, mouseX, mouseY, message);
}
```

Expecting to draw "hello world"
However actual result is "hello"

Comment: You are not checking if the character (`s[i]`) is a space, but if the current index (`i`) is equal to the ascii value of a space. I think you don't need your check at all. And you should use `size_t i = 0`, because that type is returned by `s.length()`.

Comment: Amazing this worked perfectly. I made so many changes while debugging that I ended up adding more code than necessary and this extra code was causing the issue. removing the check for a space was all that was necessary, thank you!

Comment: Alright, you should still fix the type if the `i` variable. Otherwise you'll get into trouble for strings with more than 255 characters.